# How to run cmd.exe and a lot of switches via cmd.exe in Process.Start()

Tags: c#, process

Similar to a previous question, I sometimes run this command on cmd.exe:

```
Rundll32 Printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /K /q /m "SHARP MX-5500N PS" /h "Windows NT x86" /v 3 /f sn0hwenu.inf
```

If I want to run this via Process.Start(), is everything up to PrintUIEntry the filename and the rest arguments? Do I need to concat cmd.exe at the front of the above string (I am assuming yes anyway), and if that is the case, then is that the file name and the rest arguments. Is there any rule of thumb here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ProcessStartInfo to specify the file to run (rundll32) and the Arguments property to specify the arguments to use. It is not an array, but a string.

startInfo.Arguments = "/x /y /z";

You don't need cmd.exe because you're starting a process which is going to be rundll32 which doesn't require cmd to host it.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "rundll32.EXE";
    startInfo.Arguments = "Printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /K /q /m "SHARP MX-5500N PS" /h "Windows NT x86" /v 3 /f sn0hwenu.inf";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Note that you may need to wrap arguments in quotes (which it looks like you're already doing). For example, if you're giving a path c:\Program Files... you will need to wrap that in quotes or you'll get errors when trying to run the process

```
startInfo.Arguments = "\"c:\\Program Files\\...\"";
```

Also keep in mind that specifying rundll32.exe alone might not work. I'm not sure if process.Start uses PATH environment variables to resolve the file so you might need to give the full path to rundll32.exe

Answer (score 2):

The filename should be `Rundll32.exe`. Printui.dll,etc are arguments. You do not need `cmd.exe`, since rundll32 is its own program.